# Saving a bitmap file in android and reading back to display in Imageview

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a bitmap file which i need to upload to my php server but as the file is very large I decided to resize it and save it. Later on I try to read it back to display resized image. But this time I am not getting the same image
Below is code for writing image and returning File

```
public static File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "testimage.jpg");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
    return f;

}
```

Below is code for reading and displaying

```
File file=ImageUtil.savebitmap(this.bitmap);
            this.imgChoosenImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Please tell me what exactly is going wrong here

Comment: So you are reading the file *from the server* back to your phone then you are displaying the file? What is the format of the file that you get from the server? Is it base64?

Comment: "Below is code for reading and displaying" - That code isn't reading. It's is saving whatever you currently have in `this.bitmap`, and then setting the file URI on the `ImageView`.

Comment: @mike: i make a call to savebitmap which saves bitmap and returns the file object of saved file and from that i extract URi to display it back to imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check the images are saved in ur path as defined, and Make sure ur giving correct path for retriving image.
    I have used this below code for saving imge in gallery

```
String iconsStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator;
        File sdIconStorageDir = new File(iconsStoragePath);
        //create storage directories, if they don't exist
        sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();
        try {
            String filePath = null;
            filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "testimage" + ".jpg";
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, bos);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Create folder",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

For bitmap display in imageview :

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/testimage.jpg");
    //Here File file = ur file path
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: what is aadarCard?

Comment: @KumarGaurav did u get img in imgview ?

Comment: Yes. I was able to get image on my imageview but all i got was a black colored image. Nothing else. Which is incorrect.

Comment: first check ur getting bitmap image correctly and saving it . then check correctly that path for retrieving the image ... my code is just a snipet u need to modify it